# Do FFMPEG H264 compression presets affect the video quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am definitely not an FFMPEG expert, but according to [this document](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide):

> A preset is a collection of options that will provide a certain encoding speed to compression ratio. A slower preset will provide better compression (compression is quality per filesize).  General usage is to use the slowest preset that you have patience for. Current presets in descending order of speed are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow, placebo.

So as I understand it, the `ffmpeg` presets should not affect the quality of the output video, but should only determine the compression ratio / output file size. Consequently, assuming the same quality setting (I will use `-crf 24`), the files should be larger for e.g., `faster` preset than for the `slower` preset. That would be the only reason to use a slower preset - to get a smaller file size.

This turns out not to be the case. I encode a HD stream from a handycam using different presets, everything else is the same:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "$fname" -vf yadif=1,scale=-1:720 -acodec aac -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -threads 2 -crf 24 "$outp"
```

Surprisingly, I get the smallest file size for `veryfast` preset! For example:

- `slower`:   output bitrate  3500kbps, encoding speed 17 fps, file size 29MB
- `veryfast`: output bitrate  3050kbps, encoding speed 34 fps, file size 25MB

Which I think is not as it should be. Now I wonder, is that due to a worse encoding quality for the `veryfast` preset? Or in my case using `slower` does simply not make sense for some reason?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, quality may vary slightly depending on the preset used, but it should not be a significant amount. Here's an excerpt from a discussion on #x264. Similar question to yours with answers provided by one of the x264 developers:

```
verb3k | Do different presets have an effect on quality when used with CRF?
@Dark_Shikari | verb3k: yes, but not too much.
@Dark_Shikari | a 0th-order approximation is that they have no effect.
@Dark_Shikari | The main reason there's a difference is because the preset affects how x264 itself measures quality
@Dark_Shikari | that is, it uses better, more accurate methods of measuring quality
@Dark_Shikari | obviously, this will affect the definition of what -crf does!
@Dark_Shikari | It's just not too much, so we can mostly ignore it.
@Dark_Shikari | specifically, there are three big things that can affect the definition of quality
@Dark_Shikari | 1) AQ being on/off
@Dark_Shikari | jump: ultrafast to superfast
@Dark_Shikari | 2) mbtree being on/off
@Dark_Shikari | jump: superfast to veryfast
@Dark_Shikari | 3) psy-rd being on/off
@Dark_Shikari | jump: faster to fast
@Dark_Shikari | above fast there are no more big jumps.
```

This means that a slower preset with the same CRF value will improve quality per bitrate, but might make both quality and bitrate higher **or** lower.

Comment: Thanks for this - a very useful read. Seems clearer now, although I will have to experiment to see what 'not too much' means.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard What should I modify to reduce the chances of Conversion Fail, it's happening at random, sometimes it doesn't happen

Comment: @LordNeckbeard http://superuser.com/questions/1142205/ffmpeg-conversion-fails-due-to-network-error-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3238

Comment: No one could really advice :\ The worse is , i dont know where to look into. Tried different server, different ubuntu, latest version, different setting, googled till page 1001. Now i'm in comments

Answer (score 5):

If it helps here is a `git diff` from `slower` to `veryfast`. Even if you just consider the `ref` value you can see how `veryfast` could be lower quality.

```
ref
In short, this value is the number of previous frames each P-frame can use
as references.
```

[**source**](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings)

```
--- a/slower
+++ b/veryfast
@@ -1,20 +1,20 @@
 cabac=1
-ref=8
+ref=1
 deblock=1:0:0
-analyse=0x3:0x133
-me=umh
-subme=9
+analyse=0x3:0x113
+me=hex
+subme=2
 psy=1
 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
-mixed_ref=1
+mixed_ref=0
 me_range=16
 chroma_me=1
-trellis=2
+trellis=0
 8x8dct=1
 cqm=0
 deadzone=21,11
 fast_pskip=1
-chroma_qp_offset=-2
+chroma_qp_offset=0
 threads=12
 lookahead_threads=2
 sliced_threads=0
@@ -25,17 +25,17 @@ bluray_compat=0
 constrained_intra=0
 bframes=3
 b_pyramid=2
-b_adapt=2
+b_adapt=1
 b_bias=0
-direct=3
+direct=1
 weightb=1
 open_gop=0
-weightp=2
+weightp=1
 keyint=250
 keyint_min=23
 scenecut=40
 intra_refresh=0
-rc_lookahead=60
+rc_lookahead=10
 rc=crf
 mbtree=1
 crf=23.0
```